# Which one is right? Do I need to use which?

Tags: grammar, british-english

> I don't even know the name of planet I live on
>
> I don't even know the name of the planet which I live on
>
> I don't even know the name of the planet, I live in

(This was said with a comical sense)

Comment: The last one is "invalid" because we live ***on*** planet Earth, not ***in*** it (plus the comma is incorrectly used there). The first two are just different (but equally valid) ways of saying the same thing (there's also *I don't even know the name of the planet **on which** I live* - again, perfectly valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about a specific planet, you need to precede it with the definite article *the*. Similarly, you live ON the planet, not IN the planet. If you say that you live in the planet, that would mean that you literally live inside a planet. Would that make any realistic sense? So far, the following example would be correct:

> I don't even know the name of **the** planet I live **on**.

The use of the pronoun *which* is up to you in this case because it's oftentimes optional. You can even substitute it with the conjunction *that*. Their primary function is to link a clause giving further information to something that was previously mentioned:

> I don't even know the name of **the** planet **which** I live **on**.
>
> I don't even know the name of **the** planet **that** I live **on**.